# Name of sci-fi book with Mars and intelligent spheres of light

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

I am looking for the name of a book I read long ago.

**spoilers ahead**

The story was that some humans go to Mars for some experiment. They meet spheres of light which are the only physical remains of an earlier Martian specie. They are very intelligent and don't need a body and can communicate with the humans mentally. Later it is discovered they have a malicious intent.

**Update**

I read it 14 years ago. It was in English.

In the story, the humans we're in their spaceship (landed on Mars) most of the time and would occasionally go out of the spaceship on to the land for experiments. The intelligent lights invaded the minds of humans when they were relaxed and empty minded. Only one of the humans was able to survive for long. I am not sure if he succeeded to escape.

Comment: Here is [a previous question about "The Fire Balloons"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176115/4985)

Comment: Updated the question with more information.

Comment: @William Jackson Yes that is the one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds a lot like Ray Bradbury's *The Fire Balloons* (part of *The Martian Chronicles*), though that  involved missionaries rather than scientists and the globes weren't particularly malicious.